# Where is object id of 0 coming from in this Swift code that is supposed to pass audio from an input device to an output device? See error message

Tags: swift, core-audio, avaudioengine

I am fairly new to this and trying to learn, so please excuse if the following is not correct, but what I think it is supposed to do is:

- init an input and output node
- create an audio unit for each node
- assign a "CurrentDevice" of a particular device id for each audio unit
- connect the input and output

```
func start() {
    let engine = AVAudioEngine()
    
    let inputNode = engine.inputNode
    let outputNode = engine.outputNode
    
    guard let inputUnit: AudioUnit = inputNode.audioUnit else { return }
    guard let outputUnit: AudioUnit = outputNode.audioUnit else { return }
    
    var inputDeviceID: AudioDeviceID = 46  // External input device
    var outputDeviceID: AudioDeviceID = 57  // Mac mini speakers
    
    AudioUnitSetProperty(inputUnit, kAudioOutputUnitProperty_CurrentDevice, kAudioUnitScope_Global, 0, &inputDeviceID, UInt32(MemoryLayout<AudioDeviceID>.size))
    AudioUnitSetProperty(outputUnit, kAudioOutputUnitProperty_CurrentDevice, kAudioUnitScope_Global, 0, &outputDeviceID, UInt32(MemoryLayout<AudioDeviceID>.size))
    
    let bus = 0
    engine.connect(inputNode, to: outputNode, fromBus: bus, toBus: bus, format: nil)
    
    engine.prepare()
    do {
        try engine.start()
    } catch {
        print("error")
    }
}
```

When I run this, the logs fill with:

```
AudioObjectGetPropertyDataSize: no object with given ID 0
AudioObjectGetPropertyData: no object with given ID 0
AudioObjectGetPropertyDataSize: no object with given ID 0
AudioObjectGetPropertyData: no object with given ID 0
AudioObjectGetPropertyDataSize: no object with given ID 0
AudioObjectGetPropertyData: no object with given ID 0
...
```

Where is this ID of 0 coming from?

If I comment out either `AudioUnitSetProperty(...)`, the error does not happen.

What I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're doing looks correct to me although I usually do this using `AUAudioUnit`:

```
try inputNode.AUAudioUnit.setDeviceID(inputDeviceID)
try outputNode.AUAudioUnit.setDeviceID(outputDeviceID)
```

I don't know that in this case it will make a difference, though.

Previously there was an undocumented limitation on `AVAudioEngine` restricting simultaneous input and output to the default system device (https://www.mail-archive.com/coreaudio-api@lists.apple.com/msg01663.html). I am not sure if that limitation is still present on Big Sur.

One possible workaround (I haven't had a chance to try yet) is to create an aggregate device containing the input and output devices you'd like and use that device with `AVAudioEngine`.

`AudioObjectID` 0 is `kAudioObjectUnknown`. I suspect your attempt to set the device left the engine in an error state when it failed.

Comment: Thank you for the fast response. It is helpful, especially to read that I am on the right track. Two questions:
1) About that limitation to AVEngine restricting simultaneous input and output, how do applications like GarageBand work? In the GarageBand preference pane, there is an option to select Output Device and Input Device, which are not at all related to the system devices. I am basically trying to make _that_, without the rest of GarageBand. I figured it would be _possible_ because GarageBand can do it.

Comment: 2) When you suggest making an Aggregate Device, is that something that I would do programmatically? Or do you mean to make on in the Audio Midi utility?

Comment: Just to be clear about what I am trying to make: There is an application called BlackHole that creates a software audio device that can be chosen as the output device as a means of piping audio into applications as an input device.

I want to take that audio and send it back to an actual output device. The advantage of doing so is it will give system access to the volume control.

I am using this project as an excuse to learn more about AVAudioEngine, so that is the secondary purpose of this. Again, I appreciate your response. It is difficult to find information about any of this.

Comment: GarageBand may or may not use `AVAudioEngine` under the hood; if it does it may use private API. You can create aggregate devices programmatically using `AudioHardwareCreateAggregateDevice` although I'd try AMS first to see if it actually will work for you.

Comment: Aha. Do you have any ideas why there is such a limitation? It seems strange to have library that is meant for connecting different nodes representing audio devices and then make it impossible to connect those devices.

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea why it works that way. I agree it seems strange.